# ssh reverse connect tor

Tags: torsocks, ssh, tunnel

So, I have 2 vms: "first" and "second". On "first" start hidden tor service on port 1234, this port forward to ssh port on locahost.  From "second" i can connect to 1234 and get ssh shell. However, i`l try to create reverse connect from:  throw local port "first" connect to local port on "second". Connection established, but when connect on local port "first" failed.

Deatils:
"second"  -  torsocks ssh  -C -i priv -v -R 192.168.48.2:2222:192.168.48.1:1000 -p 80 user@dhfghdfgjhfg.onion

```
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 192.168.48.2:2222, connect 192.168.48.1:1000
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
pidr@ubuntu:~$ debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen 192.168.48.2 port 2222, originator 127.0.0.1 port 36028
1506591602 ERROR torsocks[4036]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:533)
          debug1: connect_next: host 192.168.48.1 ([192.168.48.1]:1000): Connection refused
connect to 192.168.48.1 port 1000 failed: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 3):

So , i solved the problem.
Change torsocks to ssh -o "ProxyCommand socat - SOCKS4A:localhost:%h:%p,socksport=9050"
and now a can create reverse connect from device to my server.

Comment: also
useful https://vimeo.com/141691357